# Change the timestamp of an SVN revision

Tags: svn, version-control

We had a power failure that exhausted our UPS and subsequently shutdown our SVN machine. When it booted back up it, the system time was incorrect.

Unfortunately, this was not caught until some people had already committed a changes. So now we have a few revisions that predate the first revision by several years.

Is there a way to correct this date, so things are in order?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The date/time is a property of the revision. Figure out the revision number (or use HEAD), and modify it with propset or propedit and --revprop.

```
svn propset svn:date 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.MMMMMMZ' --revprop -r HEAD /path/to/wc/file
```

You'll have to play around with it to get the right combination of settings. You can also look at the Red Book, under [Advanced Properties](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.advanced.props.html#svn.advanced.props.manip). (I linked to 1.4, adjust to suit your version).

Comment: Note: I acutally used tortoiseSVN (see CMS's response below), but I never specified that in the question.

Comment: I changed/deleted svn:date and haven't seen any difference. Any idea?

Answer (score 10):

Change the svn:date property of the revision:

```
svn propset -rXXX --revprop svn:date "2008-03-10T03:00:00.000000Z" repository
```

Or using TortoiseSVN, Show log -> Right click on the revision -> Show revision properties:

[image]

You will need for that the **pre-revprop-change** hook, a empty shell script or batch file will do the work.

Comment: hmm - an empty bat file is not working.  I get the following "'pre-revprop-change' hook failed with error output:"

Comment: @CMS - I did indeed take the tortoiseSVN path, however I'm going to accept @Andrew's answer since he was first, had the same answer (more or less), and will probably appreciate the rep more.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I guess the hook script explicitly needs to return an exit code of zero…

Answer (score 6):

1. Enable [revision property change](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.reposhooks.pre-revprop-change.html) hook
2. Modify [svn:date](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.propset.html) property, using [svnlook date](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svnlook.c.date.html) if you need.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, when using TortoiseSVN, the log is cached, and you have to delete the cache for the TortoiseSVN log on the client to reflect the changes on the server. See [Tortoise SVN Log messages does not update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44837856/tortoise-svn-log-messages-does-not-update)