# SVN commit with old date/time

Tags: svn, timestamp, commit

Is there some way how to commit into the SVN repository with old time / date or how to edit the time / date post commit?

I have some archived sources which are very old, way before I have started using SVN, and I would now like to put them into the SVN and if possible to preserve their original date, so that SVN history matches the real date where files were edited.

Manipulating SVN server time is an obvious option, but it cannot be used here, as the SVN server is out of my control.

Comment: Is this an existing repository, or a new one? Would you be overwriting directories and / or files in the repository?

Comment: An existing repository, in initial commit I will be overwriting no files, but some of them will be overwritten later. I have a bunch of archive files like sources-1995-05.zip, sources-1995-08.zip, sources-1996-01.zip and I would like to transfer their content to SVN and have dates like 1995/08/xx and 1996/01/xx with the respective commits.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/633353/change-the-timestamp-of-a-svn-revision

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did eventually was:

- install VisualSVN server on my workstation
- create a new "local" SVN repository
- take archives one by one, for each:

  - in the working copy delete everything but .svn file, to make sure files which were deleted are not left over
  - decompress the archive into the working copy
  - change system date to the date of the archive
  - add and delete as necessary and commit into the local repository
- once done, use `svnadmin dump` the repository
- on the main SVN server load the dump using `svnadmin load`

The steps above seem easier to me than installing the `pre-revprop-change` hook. (The one we currently have in place allows editing log message only.)

Note: instead of changing system date it would be also possible to edit the date in the dump file before loading it.

Comment: You can edit the dump file as long as your editor preserves any binary information and doesn't change the end-of-lines.

Answer (score 18):

The date and time is in the ["special" revision property, `svn:date`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.properties.html#svn.ref.properties.unversioned-props). You can modify it as so:

```
svn propedit svn:date --revprop -r 12345
```

or:

```
svn propset svn:date --revprop -r 12345 2009-02-12T00:44:04.921324Z
```

The revision (e.g. `12345` above) can also be `HEAD` meaning the latest revision.

The date is specified in [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

You will need the repository to have the appropriate [`pre-revprop-change`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.reposhooks.pre-revprop-change.html) hook set up (in the `hook` directory in the repository) to allow `svn:date` to be modified. The templates that are provided with SVN repositories should be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Each revision has a property, `svn:date`. If you have permission to modify unversioned properties, you can change that value.