# Svn commiting question

Tags: svn, date, commit

I need to reuplad file to repositary, but I need last modification time to be set to other value, then the contemporary time. Is there a way to:
1) Change the date of already commited file?
2) Commit file with date of my choice?

I have already tried to change it, but i get error message:
"DAV request failed; its possible that the repositorys pre-revprop-change hook either failed or is non-existent. At least one property failed; repository is unchanged. Error setting property: 'date': Revprop change blocked by pre-revprop-change hook (exit code 1) with output:
Changing revision properties other than svn:log is prohibited"

Am I right, that I just don´t have permission to edit properties of file? Is there a way to change this?

Thanx for answers

Comment: Duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101153/svn-commit-with-old-date-time?

Answer (score 1):

This is not allowed by default but can be allowed by creating **pre-revprop-change** hook on svn repository server. Check [this](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#change-log-msg) and also it's discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101153/svn-commit-with-old-date-time). If hook will allow this operation then you can modify **svn:date** property.