# Tortoise SVN Log messages does not update

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn

SVN repository keeps the log messages as properties attached to each revision. these properties are kept in `db/revprops` folder of repository with same numbering as revision. I needed to change format of the log messages and include some extra information. Format of the prop files (at least for version 7 uncompressed) is just key value in text format. I wrote a small program to do this and successfully edited the log messages.

Running `SVN Log` verifies the command line and shows updated log messages

[image: SVN Log shows updated message]

**Problem**

Opening TortoiseSVN in dev computers does not show the updated messages in list; however if developer right click on the revision item in list and select `Edit log message` the edited message will show up. Even checkout of whole repository to new folder still shows the old message.

[image: Tortoise revision list is not updated]

**Question**
Above observation makes me believe that TortoiseSVN somehow caches the log messages in client computers. Where is this information stored?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, TortoiseSVN caches the log messages and changed paths. You should be able to clear the cache via **TortoiseSVN Settings | Log Caching | Cached Repositories**.

Read [TortoiseSVN Manual | Log Caching](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-dia-logcache) & [Cached Repositories](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-logcache-repolist) for further information.

**NOTE:** Log caching is a very helpful feature. Don't disable it and be careful when you enter log messages.

Comment: Thank you. I found the cache folder under `%appdata%\TortoiseSVN\logcache` and deleted the log cache. the link you mentioned is a good read, as repository is in local network, I advised team to disable log caching too.

Comment: @AaA log caching is a very helpful feature. Don't disable it and be careful when you enter log messages.

Comment: If a user changes the svn:date value from the TortoiseSVN's Show Log | right click menu | Show Revision Props, then they can go into "TortoiseSVN Settings | Log Caching | Cached Repositories", click on the cached repo and click the "Update" button. It will pull the latest timestamps from the server & display them in the Show Log window. No need to delete, nor disable anything!

Answer (score 2):

On the SVN setting go to log caching, and under tab 'global setting' untick the checkbox 'enable log caching'. 
[image]click 'ok' . 
it shall solve your problem

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I was asking where the log is, not how to solve it